# Android Setting Custom Locale from terminal on Emulator

Tags: android, locale

How can I set custom Locale from terminal to run on android emulator? I know that there is already set custom locale app on the emulators but for pt-BR or es-US it is not working. I want to force it from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

adb shell ' setprop persist.sys.language de; setprop persist.sys.country DE; stop; sleep 5; start'